# How to add new lines on a splitted page

Tags: itext

I'm using (in Java)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm printing a header, a logo, a picture and a table on each page. Follow is the code ( a little "pseudo" ):

```
Document document = new Document( PageSize.A4 );
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream( pdfFullPath ) );
writer.setPageEvent( new HeaderAndFooter() );

    for ( some condition for each page ) {
            document.add( theLogoInLeftTop );     
            document.add( new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n\n") );  <<<-- Will give room for the heder printed by the `setPageEvent`           

            Image thumb = Image.getInstance( theImage );
            float scaler = ((document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin()
                           - document.rightMargin() ) / thumb.getWidth()) * 100;                

            thumb.scalePercent(scaler);
            thumb.setBorder( Image.BOX );
            thumb.setBorderWidth(1);
            document.add( thumb );        

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable( new float[] { 1, 3 } );
            table.setTotalWidth( document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin() );
            table.setLockedWidth(true);  


            // Too much rows will cause a page break and will print 
            // the rows over the header.
            for( some or few rows ) {
                table.addCell( someLeftText );
                table.addCell( someRightText );
            }

            document.add(table);            
            document.newPage();
    }

    document.close();
    writer.close();
```

When I have few rows all is fine and all content is printed in one page. But when I have a lot of rows a new page is started ( not my `document.newPage()` ) and the rows contents are printed over my header and logo ( they don't respect the `document.add( new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n\n") );` at begining of each page ).

How can I do a `document.add( new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n\n") );` when a new page is started by "content overflow" so I can save the header space ?

The logo is not being printed too.

This is my header creator (Just to illustrate):

```
public class HeaderAndFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
      // Printing the headers using
      // ColumnText.showTextAligned

    }

}
```

Comment: As you indicate that you are using both iText 5.5.x and 7.1.x, it is unclear from which library version the classes in your code are.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a little confusing too. Put the `core` libs but will work without it. There is no iTextPDF 7 ... Removed the CORE lib.

Comment: Sorry my english. If something is unclear please tell me.

Comment: Ok, first of all, if you need that `document.add( new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n\n") );` to *give room for the heder printed by the `setPageEvent`*, then you're already doing something wrong: One chooses the coordinates to draw headers and footers at in the top and bottom margin area of the document. If you need more space, you select larger margins. Thus, there is no need in leaving space empty in the main page body filled by `document.add` calls.

Comment: @mkl : understood you are telling me to increase the top margin and to remove the `\n` ... but how to increase only the top margin of an A4 document?

Comment: Ok. Added : `document.open();       document.setMargins(document.leftMargin(), document.rightMargin(), document.topMargin() + 80 ,document.bottomMargin() );` and removed all the new lines (`\n`) but is not working for the first page.

Comment: As you found out yourself, by setting the margins early (before `document.open()`, e.g. in the document constructor) also makes the margins count on page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
After removing all the `\n`'s I added the new margins at the document creation.

No need of `document.setMargins()`

```
float left = 30;
float right = 30;
float top = 85;
float bottom = 20;        

Document document = new Document( PageSize.A4, left, right, top, bottom );
```